# Given the square grid coordinates, how to calculate the data from a different table that falls under that range?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a bunch of coordinates in my table *grid* with the following schema **id,x1,x2,y1,y2** like these:

```
22,910000,920000,120000,130000
67,930000,940000,170000,180000
171,980000,990000,210000,220000
```

*Grid* table also has an ID for each coordinate tuple.

In a separate table *crashes* I have an information about the automobile crashes, where the last two values are '**x_coordinate**' and '**y_coordinate**' respectively.

```
2007,2,9,4,1,1028977,202232
2004,1,1,1,4,1012600,214101
2003,1,9,1,1,958775,156149
1999,1,1,1,1,997349,175503
```

1-How could I compute the number of crashes for each square grid? (display 2 columns: Grid ID and # of crashes associated with it)

*2-And if going the other direction, how would I retrieve all "square grids" (tuple of x1,x2,y1,y2) that have more than 60 crashes in the following years: 2005,2006 and 2007? (in HTML it would look like a table with 3 columns: 2005 | 2006 | 2007 and under each year - coordinate tuple(s) x1,x2,y1,y2 that meet the criteria of >=60 car crashes.*

Comment: More than 60 crashes per year or in total amount?

Comment: @MostyMostacho: 60 crashes per each year, not all three years combined. Sorry I'll make it clear in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#1 is easy:
(this originally was "How would I calculate which automobile accidents fall into the square grid of x1,x2,y1,y2 coordinates from the grid table?")

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
            grid.ID
FROM        crashes
INNER JOIN  grid    
            ON  crashes.x_coordinate BETWEEN grid.x1 AND grid.x2
            And crashes.y_coordinate BETWEEN grid.y1 AND grid.y2
```

#2 is only a bit harder:
(this originally was "how would I retrieve all "square grids" (tuple of x1,x2,y1,y2) that have more than 60 crashes in the following years...?")

```
SELECT  
            grid.ID, COUNT(*) AS CrashCount
FROM        crashes
INNER JOIN  grid    
            ON  crashes.x_coordinate BETWEEN grid.x1 AND grid.x2
            And crashes.y_coordinate BETWEEN grid.y1 AND grid.y2
WHERE       crashes.yearCol IN(2005, 2006, 2007)
GROUP BY    grid.ID
HAVING      COUNT(*) >= 60
```

---

solutions for the revised questions ...

For #1 "How could I compute the number of crashes for each square grid?", is just a simplification of the original #2:

```
SELECT  
            grid.ID, COUNT(*) AS CrashCount
FROM        crashes
INNER JOIN  grid    
            ON  crashes.x_coordinate BETWEEN grid.x1 AND grid.x2
            And crashes.y_coordinate BETWEEN grid.y1 AND grid.y2
WHERE       crashes.yearCol IN(2005, 2006, 2007)
GROUP BY    grid.ID
```

For #2 "how would I retrieve all 'square grids' (tuple of x1,x2,y1,y2) that have more than 60 crashes in (***each of***) the following years: 2005,2006 and 2007??

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT  grid.ID,
            grid.x1, grid.x2, grid.y1, grid.y2,
            (   SELECT  COUNT(*)
                FROM    crashes
                WHERE   yearCol = 2005
                  And   crashes.x_coordinate BETWEEN grid.x1 AND grid.x2
                  And   crashes.y_coordinate BETWEEN grid.y1 AND grid.y2
            )   As year05,
            (   SELECT  COUNT(*)
                FROM    crashes
                WHERE   yearCol = 2006
                  And   crashes.x_coordinate BETWEEN grid.x1 AND grid.x2
                  And   crashes.y_coordinate BETWEEN grid.y1 AND grid.y2
            )   As year06,
            (   SELECT  COUNT(*)
                FROM    crashes
                WHERE   yearCol = 2007
                  And   crashes.x_coordinate BETWEEN grid.x1 AND grid.x2
                  And   crashes.y_coordinate BETWEEN grid.y1 AND grid.y2
            )   As year07,
    FROM    grid
) As gridSum
WHERE   year05  >= 60
  And   year06  >= 60
  And   year07  >= 60
```

This one is a bit easier to do in TSQL where we have the WITH clause to work with...

Comment: The first one, returns all 12000 records. Shouldn't it only display a 120 rows or so, since that's how many Grid IDs I have?

Comment: It depends on the details of the data in the rows.  I have corrected it for the case you described.

Comment: Barry sorry for the confusion, it's not it still. I've revised my first question so hopefully it's clear now what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

This will get you which GridId a crash occurred in the crashes table.  I assume you meant the BETWEEN shortcut mentioned below instead of the >= and <=

```
SELECT
     crashes.*
    ,(
        SELECT grid.id
        FROM grid
        WHERE
                crashes.x_coordinate BETWEEN grid.x1 AND grid.x2
            AND crashes.y_coordinate BETWEEN grid.y1 AND grid.y2
     ) AS GridId
FROM crashes
```

as for second question of crashes in a grid between years try this

```
SELECT GridId, SUM(CrashesInGrid) AS TotalCrashesInGrid
FROM
(   
    SELECT T.GridId, T.year, COUNT(*) AS CrashesInGrid
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
             *
            ,(
                SELECT grid.id
                FROM grid
                WHERE
                        crashes.x_coordinate BETWEEN grid.x1 AND grid.x2
                    AND crashes.y_coordinate BETWEEN grid.y1 AND grid.y2
             ) AS GridId
        FROM crashes
    ) AS T
) AS T2
WHERE T2.year >= 2005 AND T2.year <= 2007
GROUP BY T2.Year
HAVING SUM(CrashesInGrid) >= 60
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't solve the first question any better than Barry :)

However, does this solve the second one? Let me know if it doesn't.

```
SELECT id FROM (
  SELECT g.id, c.yearCol, COUNT(*) CrashCount FROM crashes c
  INNER JOIN grid g
  ON c.x_coordinate BETWEEN g.x1 and g.x2 AND c.y_coordinate BETWEEN g.y1 AND g.y2
  WHERE c.yearCol IN (2005, 2006, 2007)
  GROUP BY g.id, c.yearCol
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 60
) final
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(yearCol) = 3
```