# Find all square grids with fewer crashes in 2007 than in 1989?

Tags: mysql, sql

My *nycgrid* table with the following schema `id,x1,x2,y1,y2`. And it looks like following examples:

```
22,910000,920000,120000,130000
67,930000,940000,170000,180000
171,980000,990000,210000,220000
```

Another table, *nyccrash*, contains tuples with information about the car acciddents that occured from 1989 through 2007 (12 thousand records in total). The first attribute is **crash_year**, followed by type of accident, weather condition...etc and ending in **x_coordinate** and **y_coordinate** where the car crash has occurred in NYC.

```
2007,2,9,4,1,1028977,202232
2004,1,1,1,4,1012600,214101
2003,1,9,1,1,958775,156149
1999,1,1,1,1,997349,175503
```

This is an extension question to the one I've asked earlier on stackoverflow.

> I am trying to find the square grids (Grid ID) such that they have
>   less car crashes occurred in 2007 than in 1989. There are about 100
>   rows in the *nycgrid* table. I need only those rows that have had less
>   accidents happened in the year in 2007 than in the year 1989.
>
> And second part, which is probably slightly easier is how could I find
>   the number of car crashes per each square grid (nycgrid.id)? In other
>   words, how display how many crashes occurred on each grid id? Each
>   crash has associated x and y coordinate. Each grid has a x1-x2-y1-y2
>   coordinates that make up a square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with [RBarryYoung's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10022465/119477) to your last question we just pivot on the year using `SUM/CASE` and then compare the values

```
SELECT ID
FROM

    (SELECT  
                grid.ID, 
                SUM(CASE WHEN yearCol = 1989 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) CrashCount_1989,
                SUM(CASE WHEN yearCol = 2007 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) CrashCount_2007
    FROM        crashes
    INNER JOIN  grid    
                ON  crashes.x_coordinate BETWEEN grid.x1 AND grid.x2
                And crashes.y_coordinate BETWEEN grid.y1 AND grid.y2
    WHERE       crashes.yearCol IN(1989, 2007)
    GROUP BY    grid.ID) t
WHERE CrashCount_2007 < CrashCount_1989
```